# Representation of locally profinite group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, langlands-conjectures

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$In Bushnell and Henniart's "[The local Langlands conjecture for $\GL_2$](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-31511-X)", Chapter 1, 3.5, proof of the duality theorem it says

> For each $g \in \mathcal G$, we choose a basis $\mathcal W_g$ of the space $W^{H \cap g K g^{-1}}$.  … Let $\mathcal{W}_g^*$ denote the basis of $\check{\mathcal{W}}_g=\Hom_{\mathbb{C}}(W^{H\cap gKg^{-1}},\mathbb{C})$ dual to $\mathcal{W}_g$.

It assumes that $G$ is locally profinite, $H$ is a closed subgroup, $(\sigma,W)$ is a smooth complex representation of $H$ with countable dimension, and $K$ is a compact open subgroup in $G$. But I think for the dual set to be the dual basis, we also need that $W^{H\cap gKg^{-1}}$ is finite dimensional, but $\sigma$ is not assumed to be admissible. I'll appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: Are you sure it says exactly what you have written?  $W^{H \cap g K g^{-1}}$ is a subspace, so it is never a basis of anything.  Moreover, what do you mean by "dual set", if not "dual basis"?

Comment: Actually Bushnell–Henniart let $\mathcal W_g$ be a basis of $W^{H \cap g K g^{-1}}$, and then explicitly define, for each $g \in H\backslash G/K$ and each $w \in \mathcal W_g$, a function $f_{g, w}$.  Then they claim that these $f_{g, w}$ form a basis for the compactly induced representation, *not* the dual representation.  It is precisely the 'compactly' condition that guarantees we only need finite combinations.  Does this answer your question?  If not, then could you clarify your question?

Comment: Yes, he does what you said. However, what I do not understand, is the second lemma, which says that $(\Ind\delta_{H\G}\otimes \check{\sigma})$ consists of all functions $f$ such that $f|HgK$ is a finite linear combination of $f_{g,\check{w}}$. If the dual set, namely $\{\check{w},w\in W_g\}$ does not form a basis, then why is the above claim true?

Comment: Oh, I see.  I agree with you that this is an error.  In the simplest case $G = H = K = 1$, this states that $\{\check w \mathrel: w \in \mathcal W_1\}$ is a basis for $W^*$, which, as you say, is equivalent to $W$ being finite dimensional—and yet nothing in the conditions forces that.